# StaggeredGridLayout Scroll position starts from bottom on applying reverse layout

Tags: android, android-layout, staggeredgridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I had used `StaggeredGridLayout` manage in `recyclerview`, and applied reverse layout as it was required but now it always starts from bottom while I want scroll position in top, I am providing my code below, any help will be much appreciated and as I m new in android, I don't know much about `staggeredGridlayout`, so any other advice along with above help to make it better will also be a great help.

Here is the code (Showing how I applied `StaggeredGridLayout` in `recyclerview`)

**.XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/explore_page"
        android:layout_above="@+id/id_views">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 mgrid = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            mgrid.setReverseLayout(true);
            mgrid.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
            mexplore_page = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.explore_page);
            mexplore_page.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mexplore_page.setLayoutManager(mgrid);
```

So, what to add in this? which will help `recyclerview` `onStart()` to from top position rather than bottom

Comment: Have you try  mgrid.setReverseLayout(false); ?

Comment: Try mgrid.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0); or mexplore_page.smoothScrollToPosition(0); after last line of above code